# Boolean variable resets when using @property

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean

## CLASS ONE.M

```
-(void)method{

    BOOL bVar;

    bVar = [UIScreen isRetinaDisplay]; //Custom Category Used Here

    NSLog(@"%d",bVar); //Value is 1

}
```

## CLASS TWO.H

```
@implementation class_two : SKNode

@property (readonly)BOOL bVar;

@end
```

## CLASS TWO.M

```
-(void)method{

    NSLog(@"%d",_bVar); //Value is 0

}
```

When I run each method the first class sets `bVar` to 1 and prints the result, but when the second method is called within the other class `class_two` the value printed from the property is 0.

What is reseting the `bVar` variable back to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is getting set "back" to 0. You're just dealing with two completely different variables. In "class one", you're setting a local variable called `bVar` (and, by the way, immediately discarding that value as soon as you exit the method). In class two, you have a class property called `bVar`, which is backed by an instance variable, `_bVar`.

So your second example is logging an instance variable that you never appear to set. If you wanted your "class one" example to actually update the property in "class two", then you'd have to provide a reference to the specific instance of "class two" whose `bVar` property you wanted to update:

```
// ClassOne.m

- (void)updateBVarInObject:(ClassTwo *)obj
{
    obj.bVar = [UIScreen isRetinaDisplay]; //Custom Category Used Here

    NSLog(@"%d", obj.bVar); //Value is 1
}
```

I don't know the relationship between the objects associated with these two classes, but hopefully this illustrates the idea, that if you want some class to update a property in another class, it has to have a reference to that other object.

Comment: So basically I'm creating a pointer to `classTwo's` memory location which allows the `updateBVarInObject:` method to change `bVars` property value in `classTwo`?

Comment: @Mutch95 If you mean that you "pass the pointer to the `classTwo` object to the `classOne` method called `updateBVarInObject`", yes that's correct.